# Migrating an old Java EE app to Maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

When I trigger **mvn archetype:generate ... -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp** it create **\src** and **pom.xml**; Inside **\src**, Maven generate the default directories **\main** and **\test**.

What should I do in order to "migrate an old Java EE app to Maven": move my packages under \main\com\mycompany\mynewapp?

Am I "forced" to use \com as a root directory (groupId)?

Answer (score 0):

The root of your source tree should be `src/main/java`, unless you configure it. For example, put your sources under `src/main/java/com/example/` if your package name is `com.example`. Or put your sources under `src/main/java/example` if your package name is just `example`.

You can use whatever groupId and whatever package names you like: the groupId doesn't have to be similar to the package names in any way. It's just convention they are similar.